# Save and handle large amount of measuring data

Tags: c#, database

I'm about to make an C# program that will log vibrations and analyze them to find if there's any trends of increasing amplitudes over a frequency range. This will obviously include saving and handling a quite large amount of data, and since I'm new to this kind of programming I've no idea about how this should be done and would deeply appreciate some tips! I will have a few sensors so if the program could create a new database for each sensor automatically.

The data will obviously be some kind of vectors which in C# probably means lists (I'll collect the data using a DAQ unit with sampling frequency of say 60 kHz). To find trends of frequency change one would of course like to read in all the old data and compare with the new reading before saving the new reading, but I understand that'll soon be impossible. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this practically?

Many thanks in advance!

Axel

Comment: You are asking a very general question. It would be hard for anybody to give you good advice w/o more info. For example: What is the structure of the vector? (what are the dimensions? what are the values?) How do you intend to build it? what kind of computations are you going to perform?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vitality! And well, a part of the problem is that I'm not really sure about those things. To be honest I didn't even know that there was a "structure" of a vector. About the values, they will be of "small values", most of them under 3 with 3 or 4 decimals (but maybe that's not what you meant?). The calculations will be different kinds of signal processing, like RMS, FFT and maybe Wavelet. But since change in frequency is what I'm interested in, most of the saved data will be FFTs.

Comment: And if anyone is interested, the application is fault detection (like bearings, gears and so on) in different kinds of machinery.

By the way, the upvotes will come as soon as I get 2 more reputations :)

Comment: And how do you intend to identify trends? Given the FFT vector (which is an array of complex numbers) - what operations would you perform on the vectors? and on which ones? do yo need the entire set in memory? Derek has started talking about storage, but storage is something that comes from the type of handling, not vice versa.

Comment: @Vitaliy: I'll probably compare the absolute value of the FFT in some way, but I'm sure about how this should be accomplished. It mainly depends on how time consuming these kinds of calculations are, but maybe sort out the regions of frequencies of interest and calculate some kind of correlation between them is the best approach. To reduce the number of vectors and thereby the number of calculations even further one could maybe calculate some kind of mean value over a period of time and just compare the means.

Comment: When it comes to storage I have not a single clue though, besides what has already being said in this thread and what I've been able to read myself about Mysql. So every help in the right direction considered the comparison as well as storage would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

If this was large-scale with lots of machines I would suggest looking at OPC or PI.  Otherwise you probably just want to pick a database: MySQL? SQL Express? Something else...?

Think about how much data you really need. Are you keeping 60,000 measurement points a second, or do you average those readings and do one entry per second?  Or do you keep track of min / max over time intervals?  Do you run a weekly/ monthly /daily batch process of cleaning up old readings?  Just some starting points for thought...

I was staring to add another comment but it was too long, so here goes:

I know that on reddit/r/programming (which I like to read ) there is often mention of MariaDB.  It seems like it is one of the new "sexy" (by that I mean lots of people are talking about it) technologies.  This was an interesting search that showed lots of major companies switching from MySQL to MariaDB.  So that would be one to think about.  http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/search?q=mariadb  Reddit/r/programming is a good site to look at once in a while to get ideas about technologies.

You are probably ok going with any of these databases, you can always start with one and move to something else later.  Like I said, if things started really getting heavy with tons of data, you would probably want to look into OPC or Pi.  Google "Data Historian" or OPC or Pi :)  But for now, start with one of these databases and get programming.  Use google, try to find forums about data historians, vibration analysis... etc.

Comment: Many thanks Derek!
Well, there will be a lot of machines but each machine will be saved on one PC and it will only alarm when some fault (change in frequency) is detected or the trend is alarming. At least at first.

About the size and samples to save I will not have to save all of them since the time-domain isn't really relevant (when reading RMS).  How large the actual FFT will be depends of the resolution obviously, but up to 20 kHz is relevant for the measurement. 

This is somewhat of a student project by the way, in case anyone wondered :)

Comment: About the old values, I think of deleting old readings something like each month. I'll then delete the last month if there's not much difference, saving the say first month from any reparation to have a reference from an undamaged machine.

What's the difference between the database you mention, in terms of performance?

Comment: Thanks Derek!
After reading some about the different database alternatives out there I think I'll go for MySql, mainly because there is a lot of guides and information about it out there but also because one can easily convert it to MariaDB later.

I'm sorry if this is considered of topic, but does anyone with a bit more experience about databases know a good way to compare previous data of a FFT with a new reading to detect trends?

Comment: I started trying to google... it looks like you get better results searching for "Fast Fourier Transform" than for the short form, FFT.  I assume this is what you are talking about...  even better seems to be "Fast Fourier Transform Algorithm".  For example: I found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9388/How-to-implement-the-FFT-algorithm  Rock the google!  Your MySQL decision seems reasonable to me :)

Comment: Well, implementing the Fft transform should be pretty straight forward but rather than do that I'll download it. There's actually an even better and faster fft algorithm that is called fftw - "fastest fourier transform in the West". This is actually the one Matlab uses when you call the fft function. My question was more about how to save and analyse those transforms, since one obviously can't read in all vectors with every measurement to detect the trends with the new data for all frequencies. So some help there would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems to me that you need to give some more thought to the layout of the solution. You can't be thinking about storage before you have a firm grasp on the algorithm itself.

I will try to give you some guidelines regarding storage strategy that you can take into consideration:

1. If you make all the calculations in memory and need the DB only for persistence, you can simply store them as BLOBs.
2. If the vectors change over time, or if the calculations are sufficiently simple, you can store the vectors in a way that retains their structure in the DB and perform the calculation in the DB by using a stored procedures or a supported scripting language. This way you do not need to pull and put data back and forth between the DB and the application. Of course this is a bit harder because stored procedures are not very fun to write or maintain.
3. Do you really need to retain the vectors themselves? If your algorithm eventually digests them and works on the results- this is all you *actually* need to store.

Comment: Again, thanks @Vitaliy! This is exactly the kind of information I need since I don't have any experience of this sort of thing and therefore don't even know where to begin. Now I know where to start searching though, and that usually gets a long way.